# Adding data to custom module grid using FK relationship

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, grid

I've created a new module with a number of foreign keys to base magento db tables, i want to add data from the magento table (customer_entity) into my custom grid.

I have a FK relationship connecting custom_entity "customer_id" to "entity_id" in customer_entity. I would like to show both the Name and Email address of the user in the custom entity grid, how do i do this?

I understand in Magento 1 you would override prepareCollection(), how do i do this in Magento 2?

I've added the following

```
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('customer_entity');
    $this->getSelect()->join($joinTable.' as customer','amrita_practitioner.customer_id = customer.entity_id', array('*'));
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

and i'm trying to add the column as follows

```
<column name="email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Can anyone shed any light on this, i'm having a number of problems using multiple models in one module, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sophie

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can display the foreign table values by defining a class in the admin_html/ui_component/YOUR_GRID_XML_FILE as follows (GIVEN EXAMPLE IS FOR ADMIN USER with Access as the name of the controller / model )

```
 <column name="user_id" class="YOUR_COMPANY_NAMESPACE\MODULE_NAME\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AccessActions" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Once you have defined your user id field to a class we should create the file at the same path and form the data as follows:

```
  <?php

namespace YOUR_COMPANY\MODULE_NAME\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

/**
 * Class TestActions
 */
class AccessActions extends Column
{

    /**
     * @var UserFactory
     */

    protected $userFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UserFactory $userFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['access_id'])) {


                       if($this->getData('name') == "user_id"){
                         $user = $this->userFactory->create()->load($item['user_id']);
                         $item[$this->getData('name')]=[$user->getUsername()];

                       }
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

The above will post the user name instead of user id.

Comment: Hi, i've implemented this and this works but there's an issue with the column sorting. Because i'm using an external model to populate the column with data and the model i'm using only contains an id, clicking the column header orders the column by id rather than alphabetically. For example, i'm retrieving a name given an ide and the column sort should short the name NOT the id. Any ideas?